# It is not obvious to use Registered I/O (RIO) Sockets to increase the data rate of receiving TCP,is this normal？

Tags: io, winsock

I recently received a task to receive TCP data as soon as possible on Windows. After checking a lot of information, I noticed that Registered I/O (RIO) Sockets may be a good choice, because it may reduce the number of copies in data transmission. I used one of the most common TCP file senders. Without changing its code, I used ordinary sockets and Registered I/O (RIO) Sockets to receive and transmit data. As a result, the performance of the two is very close. Even I removed the step of writing to disk after receiving the data.Is this normal, or is there any optimization I need to be aware of?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

RIO makes a tradeoff for lower latency vs. memory consumption (because all registered buffers will be pinning to physical memory). Feel free to look over our implementation of RIO with TCP here: https://github.com/microsoft/ctsTraffic/blob/master/ctsTraffic/ctsRioIocp.cpp

A couple of things that are different than 'normal' sockets.

- if you are sending with RIO you will want to register for Ideal Send backlog so you know how many bytes to keep in flight (with normal Winsock APIs, the send call will pend when the ideal backlog is filled). If you look in ctsTraffic code, you'll see that I implemented that.
- if you a sending with RIO APIs then you must wait for all sends to complete before calling closesocket. With normal Winsock APIs, you don't have a "the receiver received your send" notification - send() completes once the app handed off the buffer to Winsock to send. So the normal flow for an app would be to call send() until it's done then call closesocket(). With RIO you have to take the extra step and wait for all RIOSend completions before calling closesocket. If you look in ctsTraffic code, you'll see that I also implemented that.